# Upgrading pytest causes TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable error

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

Need help upgrading `pytest`.  At 3.2.4 things work, if I move to 3.3.x or 3.4.x I get an error that I don't understand and I cannot even execute the `-h` argument.  Not sure where to start or why this is happening.  Perhaps an issue with my `virtualenv` ?

### fresh virtualenv

I did try starting with a brand new fresh virtualenv, however, I still get the same error.  Reverting to `3.2.4` fixes it.

### working:

```
$ pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.2.4, imported from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest.py
```

### upgrade to 3.3.x

```
$ pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.3.2, imported from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest.py

$ pytest --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/bin/pytest", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 59, in main
    return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 76, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 102, in pytest_cmdline_main
    config._do_configure()
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 921, in _do_configure
    self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/hitcount/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 630, in call_historic
    proc(x)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

### source:

This is for an open source project I maintain: https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount

Comment: Most likely is it an issue with your env. I just set up a frsh one an it works ootB. Python 3.6.4 with pytest 3.3.2, pipenv on Manjaro.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I did try installing a fresh new virtualenv but I get the same problem.  Revering to `3.2.4` resolves it.  SIgh.

Comment: It may be an issue with some of the plugins installed - run `pip list --format=freeze | grep pytest` to see if you have any - or with some custom code in your `conftest.py` files - do you have anything defined there? Maybe some additional hookimpls?

Comment: Try https://github.com/pypa/pipenv to create a reproducible env. pipenv install pytest gets you a working venv.

Comment: @hoefling - yes! `pytest-django==3.1.2` ... and yes, am using a custom runner for the tests ... just trying to find something useful in the error message to figure out what is going on!

Comment: probably some custom `pytest_configure` hook, but hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @hoefling - I added link to the project in the source; I haven't tried switching to pipenv yet ... don't have a lot of bandwidth for this just now but wanted to try and fix it if I could.  thanks for circling back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you encountered is a bug not in `pytest`, but in the plugin library it's based on, `pluggy`. The bug was fixed 2 months ago ([see this commit](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy/commit/dcde058f93a509b9c39409fca02100e43bb43485)), but unfortunately, the currently last version of `pluggy` (0.6.0) does not contain this fix.

You thus have two possibilities:

#### Depend on `pluggy` snapshot

This is the least invasive one. `pytest` does not require a strict version of `pluggy`, so just require the development version until the next `pluggy` release:

```
# tests/requirements.txt

coverage==4.5.1
flake8==2.5.4
mock==2.0.0
pytest==3.4.2
pytest-django==3.1.2
selenium==3.10.0
tox==2.9.1
# add some meaningful explanation here 
# so you don't forget why you need this particular snapshot of pluggy
git+https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy@dcde058f93a509b9c39409fca02100e43bb43485
```

Once the next version is released, remove the snapshot dependency and bump:

```
pluggy>0.6.0
```

#### Adapt `pytest_configure` hook

Adapt your `pytest_configure` hook so it does not return anything:

```
def configure():
    from django.conf import settings

    settings.configure(
        ...

    return settings

def pytest_configure():
    configure()
```

Don't forget to call the `configure()` function in `runtests.py` instead of `pytest_configure()` and you're good to go. However, this would be only a temporary workaround that can be reverted once `pluggy>0.6.0` is released.

Comment: +100 ! Thanks for the next level follow-through on this one.  Never, ever, would have gotten to that myself.  Kudos!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

By Upgrading pytest to 4.0.1 , This issue can be solved. The latest version of pytest >5.1 is not compatible with python >3.4.